# Is it possible (easy) to reset the scores in Ubuntu Gnome Mahjongg?

Tags: gnome, games

I play Mahjongg to relieve stress. It also helps me assess mental decline with advancing years. it is Version 1:3.22.0-3 from ubuntu-bionic-main.

Answer (score 6):

You will find the scores in `~/.local/share/gnome-mahjongg/history`

You can view the content by entering `gedit ~/.local/share/gnome-mahjongg/history` in the terminal.

To reset the scores you can just delete the file: `rm ~/.local/share/gnome-mahjongg/history`